# How to get values from a raster attached to a line in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, mapinfo

In MapInfo, using Vertical Mapper, I can do a line inspection and get the Max, Min, Mean etc values for a polyline from one or more open grids which is then added as an attribute to the polyline. I'm trying to do a similar process in ArcGIS 10.1 but have been unable to work out which tool I would need to run. Any suggestions, I have access to most extensions including Spatial Analyst and have ArcInfo level licencing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Zonal Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) in Spatial Analyst.  This will allow you to get the mean, majority, maximum, median, minimum, minority, range, standard deviation, sum, and variety (number of unique values).

While I haven't tried this tool with a polyline input, there is nothing in the help file that indicates that you can't use a polyline.

Comment: +1 It works just fine with polylines, as well as for multiple non-overlapping polylines.

Comment: I was hoping for something that added the result to the existing features.  Having a raster output isn't really what I need.